# Sqlite jdbc to read .db content from memory without intermediate file / disk I/O

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, in-memory-database, in-memory

I a project sqlite .db file is read after it is unzipped.

From performance requirements (to speed up processing), I would like to eliminate disk I/O completely and use only in-memory operations.

Currently Java code is like

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path + "");
```

where `path` is to be file location.

> SQLite supports on-memory database management, which does not create any database files.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

But how to specify unzipped `byte[] bytes` to pass in this case?